# WordPress: How to list all subcategories' first post in one page?

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I have one category has 600 subcategories,
is there any way to list all subcategories with one post from each subcategory?

- sub-1 latest post title
- sub-2 latest post title
- sub-3 latest post title
- sub-4 latest post title
- sub-5 latest post title
- sub-6 latest post title
- sub-7 latest post title
- sub-8 latest post title

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve all subcategories use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

Example:

```
$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'parent'                   => 'your_parent_category_id',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC' );

$your_categories = get_categories( $args );
```

To get the posts, loop through the result and use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => your_subcategories,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish' );

$your_posts = get_posts( $args );
```